# PHP search engine in a txt file

Tags: php, search-engine

I need to create a basic search engine with PHP to search for an ID within a .txt file but still don't know how to do it, I'm new programming :(
Any help would be much appreciated.
Here's the code I have so far.

```
 <style type="text/css">  
 td { 
        font-family:verdana,arial; 
        font-size:8pt;
        border-color:#ccc;  }  
 .header{ 
        background-color:66b50b; 
        border-style:solid; 
        border-color:#32661e; 
        border-width:1px;
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-size:10pt;
        color:ffffff;   }    
  .estiloceldaw{ 
        background-color:ffffff; 
        border-style:solid; 
        border-color:666666; 
        border-width:1px;  }     
  .estiloceldag{ 
        background-color:ddeeff; 
        color:333333; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-size:10pt;  }  
</style> 
<?php

      $criterioid=$_POST["id"]; 
      echo    $criterioid;
      $critrionombre=$_POST["nombre"]; 
      $catalogo= array();
     $datospelicula =  array("clave","titulo","sinopsis","genero","anio","precio","status");

 function TraeCatalogo()
 {

        $numregistros=0;
        $ar=fopen("catalogo.txt","r") or
        die("No se pudo abrir el archivo");   
 while (!feof($ar))   {  

 $linea=fgets($ar);
 $catalogo[] = $datospelicula =explode("|",$linea);

 $numregistros=$numregistros+1;   
 }
 fclose($ar);

 echo "numero de registros".$numregistros;

 return $catalogo; 
}


 function Muestralistado($catalogo,$criterioid,$criterionombre)
 {

  $tabla= "<table><tr colspan=6><td>Clave</td><td>Nombre</td><td>Sinopsis</td><td>Genero</td><td>Año</td><td>precio</td><td>Status</td></tr>";

  if (!isset($criterioid) || trim($criterioid) == "") 
  {
   foreach ($catalogo as $k => $pelicula) 
   {
    $clave=$catalogo[$k][0];
    $titulo=$catalogo[$k][1];
    $sinopsis=$catalogo[$k][2];
    $genero=$catalogo[$k][3];
    $anio=$catalogo[$k][4];
    $precio=$catalogo[$k][5];
    $status=$catalogo[$k][6];
    $tabla.="<tr><td>".$clave."</td><td>".$titulo."</td><td>".$sinopsis."</td><td>".$genero."</td><td>".$anio."</td><td>".$precio."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";}
   }else
   {
    $tabla.="<tr><td colspan=6>hay un criterio de busqueda!</td></tr>";
   } $tabla.="<table>"; 

   echo $tabla;
}

$catalogo2=TraeCatalogo("wa"); 
Muestralistado($catalogo2); 
//var_dump($catalogo2);
?>

<html> 
<body> Buscar Pelicula: <form action="index.php" method="post">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"> id: <input type="text" name="id"> <input type="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're having (cual es el problema que estas teniendo?)

Comment: You need to fix your code indentation, it is a big mess...

Comment: If you're new to programming, i wouldn't start with this difficulty level.

Comment: *"<vague description of goal>, no idea, <wall of code>"* - Sorry, this is not an answerable question anybody can help you with. If you want a specific answer, ask a specific question about a specific problem you're specifically stuck on trying to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi @Evan, the problem I'm having is basically I don't know how to start with the search engine :( I need to search all data within the .txt file by $clave

Comment: indentation fixed, I think!

Answer (score 0):

```
$foundText = array(); // Create an array to store your found words
```

Then, once you've opened the file:

```
  while (!feof($ar))
    {
        $dataBuffer = fgets($ar); // Load some text into buffer
        $explodedText = explode($dataBuffer, "|");

        foreach($explodedText as $item){
            if(strpos($item, $clave) != false)
                $foundText[] = $dataBuffer ;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you can iterate through each found item:

```
foreach($foundText as $textItem){
    echo 'Word found: ' . $textItem . ' <br>';
}
```

Comment: @user1886859 Great, if you get a second please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check box to the left. Thanks, good luck :)